# Passing an Object to a function that accepts a param list

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I have a function defined as follows

```
postEvent = (data) ->
 throw new Error("category is required for structured events") if not category
 throw new Error("action is required for structured events") if not action

 $window.submit 'type1', data.category, data.action, data.label, data.property, data.value
```

category and action are required, but the remaining are not. If the `data` object doesn't contain a given value, it should not be passed.

I could use an absurd number of if statements, however I suspect there's a better way.
So I'm looking for a way to unwrap the objects values and pass to the other function.

Example.

```
data = {category: 'cat1', action: 'action1', value: 1.2}
postEvent(data)
```

this should result in the following

```
$window.submit 'type1', 'cat1', 'action1', 1.2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [destructuring](http://coffeescript.org/#destructuring):

```
postEvent = ({category, action, value}) ->
  console.log category, action, value

postEvent({ category: 'foo', value: 'bar' }) #logs foo, undefined, bar
```

Then you can use `call` to apply all the argument:

```
$window.sumbit.call $window, category, action, value
```

If you need validation, I recommend a different approach:

```
DATA_ORDERING = ['category', 'action', 'value']

postEvent = (data) ->
  let stuff = Object.keys data
    .sort (a, b) -> DATA_ORDERING.indexOf(a) - DATA_ORDERING.indexOf(b)
    .map (k) -> data[k]

  let valid = stuff.every (item) -> item? #make sure non-null

  if valid then $window.submit.apply $window, stuff
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Collect the required parameters

   ```
   params = [data.category, data.action]
   ```
2. Collect all the optional parameters

   ```
   OPTIONAL = ['label', 'property', 'value']
   for prop in OPTIONAL
     params.push(data[prop]) if data.hasOwnProperty(prop)
   ```
3. Invoke the method using `apply`

   ```
   $window.submit.apply($window, params)
   ```